# How to Push the same set of values when changing fields conditionally in dynamic created fields in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a dynamic row which contains 2 dropdowns and a textbox field , we can add or remove more rows .

I have a condition where if the 1st dropdown value is selected as 'Date' , and second dropdown value is selected 'Equal To' , the Textbox field changes to Datepicker field .

And then when we press the + icon , it should add again the default rows ( 2 dropdowns and 1 textbox field ) . But now it is adding a Datepicker field when the above condition is executed .

I have created a stackblitz link for the issue - Can anyone please help ?

(Select **Date** From First Dropdown , and **Equal To** From Second . And then click on + , expectation is a new row should be added as in default) . Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a way to differentiate each of the items date, something like using `[index]`

You can define

```typescript
  showDatePicker: boolean[] = [false];
  hideValue: boolean[] = [false];
```

And convert all your properties to match this new structure.

Change

```
  showDatePicker[i] = false  // Where showDatePicker = false
  showDatePicker[i] = true  // Where showDatePicker = true
  showDatePicker[i] != true  // Where showDatePicker == false
  showDatePicker[i] =- true  // Where showDatePicker == true
  hideValue[i] = false // Where hideValue = false
  hideValue[i] = true  // Where hideValue = true
  hideValue[i] == true  // Where hideValue == true
  hideValue[i] != true  // Where hideValue == false
```

[**See Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-o71p1p?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Heyyy Thnku Owen , that worked . Was not aware we could create boolena arrays too . Thnku